# Ngx-bootstrap with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-universal

I am using angular universal in my app and I have recently implemented ngx-bootstrap for modal in my app. The problem is when I am running my app in development it works smoothly but when I am running production it shows error--

node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-backdrop.component.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

what can be done to resolve this?

Comment: You should post the HTML *output* of what you run in production. That's the only way to tell what's wrong there. Post the output HTML including all css and JavaScript links you are loading there (not the angular code).

Comment: Are you using webpack in your backend nodejs server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ngx-bootstrap with angular4 with server side rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692755/how-to-use-ngx-bootstrap-with-angular4-with-server-side-rendering)